# I am converting Images to pdf using a npm library in react native why it is giving error of null object?

Tags: react-native

I am using **react-native-image-to-pdf** library to convert images to pdf in my react native app. from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-to-pdf

```
var photoPath = ['https://images.pexels.com/photos/20787/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350','https://images.pexels.com/photos/20787/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350'];

  const myAsyncPDFFunction = async () => {
    try {
        const options = {
            imagePaths: photoPath,
            name: 'PDFName',
        };
        const pdf = await RNImageToPdf.createPDFbyImages(options);
        
        console.log(pdf.filePath);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

but this is giving error **Error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference**

I have also tried giving path as  `['./assets/a.png', './assets/b.png']`

but still getting same error

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [usage example](https://github.com/Anyline/react-native-image-to-pdf), your `photoPath` needs to be a local file path and not a remote path.

My recommendation is to first use [rn-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob) to download the remote image to the device, and then pass your new local image path to react-native-image-to-pdf. Something like:

```
RNFetchBlob
  .config({
    // add this option that makes response data to be stored as a file,
    // this is much more performant.
    fileCache : true,
  })
  .fetch('GET', 'http://www.example.com/file/example.png', {
    //some headers ..
  })
  .then(async (res) => {
    // the temp file path
    console.log('The file saved to ', res.path())

    const options = {
      imagePaths: [res.path()],
      name: 'PDFName',
    };
    const pdf = await RNImageToPdf.createPDFbyImages(options);
  })
```

Comment: can you please give me the example of giving local image path from device

Comment: Updated my answer with a sample implementation for creating a single file pdf.

Comment: Sir @dansiemens I've tried this code image is successfully downloading from link and I can saw its path in console logs but still getting error. Value for imagePaths can't be cast from sting to Readable array

Comment: Edited, I think the piece missing was that `res.path()` just needs to be wrapped in an array.

Comment: thanks @dansiemens, all the errors are gone and I have printed pdf.filePath at the end and its giving ```pdf file path =>  /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.test/files/PDFName``` but can't find this in my device. can you please guide me a little about this

Comment: From the GitHub repo, that path is only accurate for Android 9 and lower. What version of Android are you on?

Answer (score 1):

replace('file://', '') it's work for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

from file path remove the text 'file://; with empty string('').

```
const options = {
                  imagePaths: [uri.replace('file://', '')],
                  name: 'FileName',         
                  quality: .9, // optional compression paramter
                };
```